# Div's overlapping when browser size changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm new to the web dev thing, but I can't find a solution to my problem.
I have two divs, and when you change the browser screen to the smallest size or open it on mobile my two divs overlap.
The two research bubbles will just overlap if you make the window small.
This is the website in action:
http://gwensume.com/RKLResearch.html

There's a lot of code here sorry about that... I've tried changing the div's to relative instead of absolute but that create these large white boxes..

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Richard K. Larson</title>

     <!-- Bootstrap -->
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- RKL CSS -->
       <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RKL.css"/>
     </head>
     <body>
   <!-- ### Header Begin ### -->

       <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
         <div class="container">
         <div class="name hidden-xs">
         <h1>Richard K. Larson</h1>
         <h4>Professor, Linguistics</h4>
         /div>
           <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle " data-       toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
               <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
               <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
               <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">Richard Larson</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right " role = "navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="RKLResearch.html">Research</a></li>
        <li class = "dropdown">
          <a href="#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown" aria-expanded = "true"> Publications <b class = "caret"></b></a>
            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="RKLArticles.html"> Articles </a></li>
              <li><a href="RKLBooks.html"> Books </a></li>
              <li><a href="RKLSoftware.html"> Software </a></li>
              <li><a href="RKLPresentations.html"> Presentations </a></li>
              <li><a href="RKLUnpublished.html"> Unpublished </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="RKLPJ.html">Port Jefferson</a></li>    
        <li><a href="RKLContact.html">Contact</a></li>  
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="darkBG2 col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <h3>The Structure & Projection of DP:</h3>
             <p>LOTS OF TEXT
            </p>
        </div>
    <div class="darkBG3 col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <h3>The Comparative Grammar of Intensional Transitive Verbs: </h3>
                    <p>MORE TEXT!
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    EVEN MORE TEXT!
                    </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space"></div>
```

CSS:

```
        html {
background: url(backgroundlyra.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
 }

h1 {font-size: 4vw;}
h4 {margin-top: -10px;}


.navbar {
background-color: #B8B8B8;
font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
color: #CD5C5C;
opacity: .95;
position: fixed;
display: inline;
}
 body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
 }

.footer p {
display: inline;
margin-right: 15px;
padding-top: 60px;
bottom: 0;
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
}

.navbar p {
margin-top: -10px;
font-size: 15px;
}

.darkBG {
background: #B8B8B8;
position: absolute;
top: 160px;
right: 50px;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity: .95;
font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 50%;
 }

 .darkBG2 {
background: #B8B8B8;
position: absolute;
top: 20vh;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity: .95;
font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
margin: 100px;
display: inline;
height: 30%;
  }

.darkBG3 {
background: #B8B8B8;
position: absolute;
top: 55vh;
border-radius: 10px;
opacity: .95;
font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
display: inline;
margin: 100px;
height: 60%;
}

img {
margin-left: 4%;
top: 160px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 10px;
max-width: 100%;
height: 21vh;
width: 21vw;
 }

.navbar-brand {
color: #CD5C5C;
}

.space {
opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given absolute positions for the divs. That's why bootstrap is not able to arrange them correctly. Remove `position:absolute;` in divs with classes `darkBG2`,`darkBG3` to fix this issue. [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```
.darkBG2 {
  background: #B8B8B8;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 20vh; */
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: .95;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-left: 15vw;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;}

.darkBG3 {
  background: #B8B8B8;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 55vh; */
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: .95;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-left: 15vw;
}
```

You'll see two issues after making these changes.

To fix the background change

```
body{
background:transparent;
}
```

To fix navbar over content issue

```
.container{
margin-top: 40vh;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks! a little more tweaking and its perfect thanks so much!!  Other than the navbar fix, that just made it huge, what was issue you saw with it?

Comment: @Gwen - how is this accepted answer? this is a hack and what I've told you to do is the correct way.

Comment: @vsync How is this a hack? I've just removed some unnecessary styles from his code. His columns were overlapping because of absolute positioning. I've removed that part and its working the way bootstrap columns normally should. Please check the link he shared. I've done nothing wrong here.

Comment: I can't accept both answers i dont think..sorry I hope I didn't do anything wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Well, what did you expect? you didn't put a new `.row` element, but instead used 2 `col-xs-9 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8` classed bootstrap elements one after the other, which gave the misleading effect of rows, but it's not suppose to work this way. if you want to show 2 rows, then just write the html as you want it to appear. maybe quick look at the [bootstrap reference guide](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) will show you how how bootstrap is to be used